# Transit visa to Australia for sri lankan passport

Tags: visas, transit, australia, sri-lankan-citizens

I am going to Singapore through Australia. I have a Sri Lankan passport. But it is just a layover for 2 hours. Do I need to apply for a transit visa for that?

Answer (score 1):

The list of countries eligible for Transit Without Visa (TWOV) is available on the Australian [Home Affairs web site](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa). Sri Lanka is not on that list - you'll need a transit visa.

You can apply for a transit visa (subclass 771) [here](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771)